# How to underline words after spell check using Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio, tmemo, trichedit, synedit

I'm trying to develop a text editor with spell checker capability. I can detect erroneous words successfully.

Many text editors underline (red color) the erroneous words like this.

[image]

How can I underline any word this way? Any TMemo, TRichEdit or TSynEdit solution is acceptable.

Comment: `TMemo` and `TRichEdit` do not support that capability natively. You would have to subclass and custom-draw them manually.

Comment: Or you could use 3d party Componts with ready implemetations.